# Consulta lenguaje SQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

Tengo una duda en cuanto una consulta SQL, necesito obtener el promedio de presupuestos de todos los departamentos y solo mostrar los que están por encima de este, entonces yo estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
  codigo,
  nombre,
  presupuesto
FROM
  departamentos
GROUP BY
  codigo,
  nombre,
  presupuesto
HAVING
  presupuesto > AVG(presupuesto)
```

De verdad no logro comprender por qué ese Query no funciona, yo lo resolví haciendo:

```
SELECT * FROM
  departamentos
WHERE
  presupuesto > (SELECT AVG(presupuesto) FROM departamentos)
```

Solo quisiera que alguien por favor me explicara por qué la primera instrucción no funciona para este caso.

Sin más que decir, un saludo!

EDIT:

Con no funciona me refiero a que no da los resultados que espero, el primer Query me da una tabla vacía, la segunda me da  la tabla de los departamentos que superan el presupuesto medio.

Comment: qué significa No funciona? sale un error? salen datos diferentes? Añade a tu pregunta algún par de registros y el resultado esperado de la consulta.

Comment: no funcion porque AVG(presupuesto) no sabe que es lo que es.. ahi o pones un select (Como tu otro ejemplo) o pones un valor...

Comment: Buenas, ya edite la pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para la primera consulta. Porqué no aparece resultados?

Se esta agrupando por codigo, nombre **y presupuesto**, por lo que nunca el promedio del mismo valor presupuesto sera menor al valor de presupuesto (de hecho sera igual al promedio).

Ademas, si `codigo` es un campo de **valor unico** (clave primaria o indice unico), al agrupar por codigo tampoco arrojara un promedio distinto de un unico elemento.

La segunda consulta refleja lo que se necesita en este caso: mostrar registros individuales filtrandolos por un valor agregado.

Finalmente, una consulta con GROUP BY no esta hecha para arrojar registros individuales ya que su finalidad es agruparlos y obtener valores de agregado (suma, promedio, minimo , maximo). Cualquier GROUP BY que separe registros unicos  no tendra ningun efecto de agrupacion.